# How to return a new arrays via method while inputs are "string name" and "int size"

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, return, declaration

I will try to make clear my problem :
Let's assume that i have a coach company and my buses has a few different service lines.

My aim is to separately store data of services for per service in in a string array "string[]".

As my thought, the name of array must be consist of (Date time + service number)

The dream was to put all passenger and the number of sold coaches information into a `string[]`

For instance :

```
//** "2303201601" >>> day + month + year + service number  
string[] "2303201601" = new string[44]; // of course doesn't work :P
```

so i tried my chance with the following code :

```
public static Array new_list (string name_list, int size)
    {
        string [] name_list = new string[size];

        return name_list;
    }
```

Please help me :D ?

Comment: Why do you care what the name of your variable is in code?  The name of the code variable is not the same as "the name of the array".  I can do `string[] 2303201601 = new string[44];` and then `string[] otherNameArray = 2303201601` and there are now two different "names" for the same array instance.

Comment: [Stringly Typed](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) *A riff on strongly typed. Used to describe an implementation that needlessly relies on strings when programmer & refactor friendly options are available...Excessively stringly typed code is usually a pain to understand and detonates at runtime with errors that the compiler would normally find.*

Comment: i.e. why are you using an object as a string and not an object?

Comment: maybe a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) can solve your problem...

Comment: so anyway. Why a string? this smells of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Why string? Even 'object'  gives an error :p

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think this is what you want, though your question is not clear. Build an object to hold all your data **properly**. Strings make bad objects

```
public class Bus
{
   public Bus()
   {
       ServiceNumbers = new List<string>();
   }

   public DateTime Date {get; set;}
   public int ServiceNumber {get; set;}
   public List<string> ServiceNumbers {get; set;}
}
```

Now just use it

```
List<Bus> buses = new List<Bus>();
Bus busx = new Bus()
{
   Date = new DateTime(year, month, day),
   ServiceNumber = "X"
}

busx.ServiceNumbers.Add("servicenumberx");
buses.add(busx);
```

I'm presuming here that the string is just a storage mechanism and there is no special reason for it. i.e. you have another piece of technology that holds string only, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer mate ..! :)

Comment: Glad to help @yucelozyazgan, BTW, it's well worth all new users to have a look though the [help].

Comment: hi Liam, i couldn't run the code .. :/ 
may you check it again for me ? thank you ...

Comment: programmer world has a different beauty ;)

Comment: Missed the type, try now

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dictionary. It will be like this:

```
var someVar=new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
someVar.Add("date+servnum", yourarray);
var yourArray = someVar["date+servnum"];
```

Comment: i haven't thought it before ..  you woke me up fro that way ! i will try ;)
thanks for you answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
public class service{
private string name;
private string[] info;
public service(string name,int size){ this.name=name; info=new string[size];
public getInfo(){ return info;}
}
```

And then, if you need an array of services you can do it:

```
 List<services> allServices=new List<services>();
```

I do not know if I understand the problem correctly

Comment: thanks for your answer ;)